# getSelection().addRange(range) works in all browsers but not in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript

Selected node to the cursor Position. It works in all browsers but not in Microsoft Edge. There is no script error. But Edge does not select the node / text?

```js
   var selection = frames[1].getSelection();
   node = selection.anchorNode;
   
   node = node.parentNode;

   if(node) {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(node);
      frames[1].getSelection().addRange(range);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem in Edge, the solution was to remove all ranges before I add a new Range.

```
...
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Looks like Edge's `Range.toString()` implementation didn't work correctly. So, commenting out the method on line 2277 (rangy-core.js) has solved the problem:

```
//rangeProto.toString = function() {
//    return this.nativeRange.toString();
//};
```

After this Rangy will use its own `toString`.

The issue [#368](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/issues/368) is opened for this problem.

Cheers!